# Latency on Bluetooth Connection using Winsock2

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino, winsock

I'm trying to use the WinSock2 API to read information I'm sending from an Arduino mega using an HC-06 Bluetooth Transmitter.  Ultimately, I plan to use this Arduino setup as a motion controller in a Unity game.  I've managed to get all the information, but in-game all inputs appear to be delayed by one second.

I tracked the problem back to my call to recv on the bluetooth socket.  Here's the offending code:

```
static int readNext(void * buffer, size_t bufferLength) {
    int ret = -1;
    if (isConnected()) {
        ret = recv(sock, (char*)buffer, (int)bufferLength, 0);
        if (ret == 0 || ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cleanupSocket();
            ret = -1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

static void waitForNext(void * buffer, size_t bufferLength) {
    size_t received = 0;
    while (isConnected() && received < bufferLength) {
        select(0, &fset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        received += readNext(((char*)buffer) + received, bufferLength - received);
    }
}
```

I call waitForNext in a worker thread inside a tight loop.  Everything else in this loop has trivial runtime (less than one millisecond in total).  Since I'm transmitting at a constant frequency that is far lower than this loop's frequency, I expected to see recv getting single bytes at a time that my other code then reconstitutes into a frame.  Instead, for roughly nine out of ten frames (though this isn't constant), I get all thirteen bytes from recv in less than one millisecond.  For the last frame, my code hangs inside the select call for anywhere from 70 to 200 milliseconds.  The same thing also happens when I remove the select call (turning the waitForNext function into a busy-wait loop), so it doesn't seem to be Windows just not waking my thread promptly enough.

What is the explanation for this behavior, and how can I eliminate it?